# Format type in logging

Tags: python, logging, format

I know basics of string formats in python but I can't understand format used
in the basicConfig method of logging !

```
FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```

[see Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

What is purpose of `%(string)s` type format and when they are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`printf`-style formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

The right operand of `%` can be tuple or a dictionary (or other mapping).

When the tuple is used, `%d`, `%s`, .... are replaced with corresponding item in order.

When the dictionary is used, `%(key)d`, `%(key)s`, ... are replaced with the value of corresponding `key` in the dictionary.

For example,

```
>>> FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(clientip)s %(user)-8s %(message)s'
>>> FORMAT % {'asctime': '2017-02-11', 'clientip': '1.2.3.4',
              'user': 'who', 'message': 'blah'}
'2017-02-11      1.2.3.4 who      blah'
```

Using of `%(key)d` / dictionary has some benefits:

- You don't need to specify format specifier in order.
- You can repeat same key multiple times: `'%(num)d + %(num)d = %(double)d' % {'num': 3, 'double': 3 * 2}`